# Mutate datasheet through a loop

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have two dataframes with Countries as rows and columns, one sheet is filled with a complete list of countries (190x190), blank data, and the other is of countries containing data (171x180). I merge them together to try and overlay the sheet containing data over the blank sheet to create a master list of countries/data.

I have used this method and determined that it works to mutate 1 column of data,

```
dff <- left_join(Country,Trade, by = "Country") %>%
  mutate(Afghanistan = ifelse(is.na(Afghanistan.x), Afghanistan.y, Afghanistan.x)) %>%
  select(-Afghanistan.y, -Afghanistan.x)
```

but wish to loop it over the entire sheet, how can this be done?

**Example Data

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1:3, nrow = 5, ncol = 6))
y <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 10))

row.names(x)=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
colnames(x)=c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V5", "V6", "V8")
row.names(y)=c("1",  "2",  "a",  "b",  "5",  "c",  "7",  "d",  "9",  "e")
```

The solution of

```
y[row.names(x), colnames(x)] <- x
```

has been recommended but this method generates rows out of order as well as extraneous columns for some reason.

Sample of blank matrix
[image: Sample of blank matrix]

Sample of data matrix
[image: Sample of data matrix]

The data matrix is missing the Angola column, among others, while the blank matrix has no data. I would like to overlay the data matrix ontop of the blank matrix to fill it out, while perserving the order of countries found in the blank matrix.

Comment: For your example data, what would your desired result look like?

Comment: Also, as long as your real data is not sensitive, you can share small samples using dput(). Use dput() with the name of your data objects with applicable filtering. (examples: `dput(df)`, `dput(head(df))`, or `dput(df[,1:4])` ) and edit your question with that sample. This will allow us to provide an answer that matches your need.

Comment: The solution in your question works: ```all_countries <- c("Afg", "Brz", "Czc", "Dmk");
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("Afg", "Brz", "Czc"), c("Brz", "Czc"))));
data_all <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(all_countries, all_countries)));
data_all[row.names(data), colnames(data)] <- data;
data_all``` Did you set the Country column to be rownames? Also, the colmn names need to match, watch out for the dot spacing in Antigua.and.Barbuda

Comment: I've added clarification to what I hope to achieve as well as some sample data in the form of pictures for better understanding of what I am working with

Answer (score 1):

One approach to complete your matrix of data could be to pivot your trade data from wide to narrow, fill in the missing countries, then pivot wide again.

```
all_countries <- c("Afg", "Brz", "Czc", "Dmk")
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, 
    dimnames = list(c("Afg", "Brz", "Czc"), c("Brz", "Czc"))))
# available for some but not all combinations of countries
data
#     Brz Czc
# Afg   1   4
# Brz   2   5
# Czc   3   6
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
data <- rownames_to_column(data, var = "country1")
#   country1 Brz Czc
# 1      Afg   1   4
# 2      Brz   2   5
# 3      Czc   3   6
```

Converting the data from wide to skinny gives you one row for each pair of countries. The `factor` class is a way of providing metadata about possible levels present in categorical data, and the order of reporting those levels.

```
data_skinny <- pivot_longer(data, 
    cols = !country1,
    names_to = "country2", 
    values_to = "trade") %>% 
    # factor levels are used by tidyr::complete to fill in missing values
    mutate(data_skinny, 
        country1 = factor(country1, levels = all_countries), 
        country2 = factor(country2, levels = all_countries))
data_skinny
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   country1 country2 trade
#   <fct>    <fct>    <int>
# 1 Afg      Brz          1
# 2 Afg      Czc          4
# 3 Brz      Brz          2
# 4 Brz      Czc          5
# 5 Czc      Brz          3
# 6 Czc      Czc          6
```

The `complete` function adds missing rows based on the factor columns specified.

```
data_all <- complete(data_skinny, 
    country1, country2)
data_all
# # A tibble: 16 x 3
#   country1 country2 trade
#   <fct>    <fct>    <int>
# 1 Afg      Afg         NA
# 2 Afg      Brz          1
# 3 Afg      Czc          4
# 4 Afg      Dmk         NA
# 5 Brz      Afg         NA
# 6 Brz      Brz          2
# ...
```

Turn back to a wide matrix, one column for each country.

```
data_all <- pivot_wider(data_all, 
    names_from = country2, values_from = trade) %>% 
    column_to_rownames(var = "country1")
data_all
#     Afg Brz Czc Dmk
# Afg  NA   1   4  NA
# Brz  NA   2   5  NA
# Czc  NA   3   6  NA
# Dmk  NA  NA  NA  NA
```